# Moving from MySQL to MariaDB

Tags: java, mariadb, wildfly

I am transferring my database from MySQL to MariaDB.

The data transfer process is now complete. However, I have a problem with connecting the driver to WildFly.

After WildFly startup, I get an error:

```
2019-12-22 09:47:18,985 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "mariadb")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0115: Module for driver [org.mariadb] or one of it dependencies is missing: [org.mariadb]"
```

---

I am looking for the solution but nothing works.

My `module.xml`:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="org.mariadb">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mariadb-java-client-2.5.2.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

---

and `standalone.xml`:

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/MariaDBDS" pool-name="MariaDBDS" enabled="true" statistics-enabled="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/bgdb</connection-url>
        <driver>mariadb</driver>
        <new-connection-sql>SELECT 1</new-connection-sql>
        <security>
            <user-name>user</user-name>
            <password>pass</password>
        </security>
        <validation>
            <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
            <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
            <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
        </validation>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="mariadb" module="org.mariadb">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

The `<datasource>...</datasource>` was added from one of the solution from web.

---

Here is my directory structure:

```
modules
└─ system
   └─ layers
      └─ base
         └─ com
            └─ mariadb
               └─ main
                  ├─ mariadb-java-client-2.5.2.jar
                  └─ module.xml
```

Comment: mariadb-java-client-2.5.2-sources.jar contains only the sources, you need mariadb-java-client-2.5.2.jar

Comment: I download the client and change the filename in module.xml but it does not help

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and solution.

The configuration files `module.xml` and `mariadb-java-client-2.5.2.jar` was in `/modules/system/layers/base/com/mariadb/main`.

But the java package of `mariadb-java-client-2.5.2.jar` is `org.mariadb`. So the files have to be in corresponds direcotry `/modules/system/layers/base/org/mariadb/main`.

After this change everything works properly.